# Referencing boost library when create R package for C++ code

Tags: c++, r, boost

I am creating an R package which calls C++ function. The code in C++ reference a boost library.

```
Rcpp.package.skeleton("cpackage")
Rcpp::compileAttributes()
```

Copied relevant .cpp and .h files in src folder
I have build the file successfully using

```
    R CMD build cproject

When I install the package it gives me following error:

> R CMD INSTALL cproject_1.0.tar.gz
In R CMD INSTALL
* installing to library 'C:/Users/user1/Documents/R/win-library/3.4'
* installing *source* package 'cproject' ...
** libs

*** arch - i386
c:/Rtools/mingw_32/bin/g++  -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.3/include" -DNDEBUG  -I"C:/Users/user1/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/Rcpp/include"        -O2 -Wall  -mtune=generic -c abc.cpp -o abc.o
In file included from abc.cpp:1:0:
Euler.h:6:53: fatal error: boost/math/special_functions/binomial.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include <boost/math/special_functions/binomial.hpp>
                                                     ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.3/etc/i386/Makeconf:215: abc.o] Error 1
Warning: running command 'make -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.3/etc/i386/Makeconf" -f "C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-34~1.3/share/make/winshlib.mk" SHLIB_LDFLAGS='$(SHLIB_CXXLDFLAGS)' SHLIB_LD='$(SHLIB_CXXLD)' SHLIB="cproject.dll" OBJECTS="abc.o abcT.o RcppExports.o rcpp_hello_world.o"' had status 2
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'cproject'
* removing 'C:/Users/user1/Documents/R/win-library/3.4/cproject'
```

How can I reference boost library while building the package?

Comment: Are you using Rcpp? If yes you can try to include the `boost` headers by adding `LinkingTo: Rcpp, BH` to your DESCRIPTION file.

Comment: Also add `// [[Rcpp::depends(BH)]]` at the beginning.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent That would be used for a single file together with `sourceCpp`, not for a package.

Comment: @RalfStubner I use that in a package of mine. So this is useless? Ok, I didn't know.